# How do I deploy a clickonce application through a website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I published the application to my file system to the web application's files (I'm running it on visual studio 2010) and made the application "download" the "setup" file to my desktop. But when I tried to execute the setup – it was missing files. Is the only way to deploy a clickonce application to have users download more than one file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to download any files - just point to the setup.exe file (local or web).
ClickOnce is just an packaging format with the ability to update from either local path/network spare or an URL. If you want to be able to install the app from a website, just put the clickonce files on an IIS and install from there e.g. c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myclickonceapp and point to http://[IP address]/myclickonceapp/setup.exe .
Remember to setup your update URLs/paths correctly in the project properties - this may be causing your problems when installing locally.